# Codechef - Monkey Power(Problem Code: MPOW)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking at this challenge on [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/LOGI2020/problems/MPOW/):

> There are *n* trees in a row and you have been given the height of these
> trees. On each tree there is one monkey and each monkey have (sic)
> particular power to climb the tree. Power of each monkey can be
> calculated as *π*(*x*). Where *x* is the total number of maximum consecutive
> trees (I.e. to the left of the current tree including itself also)
> which has height less than or equal to the height of the current tree.
> Print the maximum power that can be obtained among *n* monkeys. Here
> *π*(*x*) can be stated as: - *π*(*x*)=(*x*)∗(*x*−1)∗(*x*−2)................1.
>
> You have to answer *t* independent test cases.
>
> Output the answer modulo 10^9+7.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Sample input: -
>
> ```
> 1
> 6
> 6 4 12 3 6 7
> ```
>
> #### Output: -
>
> ```
> 6
> ```
>
> ### EXPLANATION:-
>
> For the first tree smaller or equal to itself to the
> left is only none. So, for the first monkey power will be *π*(1) =1. For
> the second tree smaller or equal to its left is none so *π*(1)=1.For the
> third tree the tree which is smaller or equal to its left is
> *π*(3)=6.And similarly for the rest of the trees.

## My Code:

```
def power(x):
    if x==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x*power(x-1)
for _ in range(int(input())):
    mod = 10**9 + 7
    number = int(input())
    trees = list(map(int,input().split()))
    stack = []
    list1 = []
    for i in range(number):
        if len(stack)==0:
            list1.append(-1)
        elif stack[-1]>trees[i]:
            list1.append(trees.index(stack[-1]))
        elif stack[-1]<=trees[i]:
            while len(stack)>0 and stack[-1]<=trees[i]:
                stack.pop()
            if len(stack)==0:
                list1.append(-1)
            else:
                list1.append(trees.index(stack[-1]))
        stack.append(trees[i])
    list2 = [0]*number
    for i in range(number):
        list2[i]= i- list1[i]
    x = max(list2)
    print(power(x)%mod)
```

CodeChef is giving me a runtime error. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Why haven't you added the modulus inside ```power()```? That's the correct way to do so

Comment: Could you explain how your algorithm (should) work? I'd use a binary tree to find the number of smaller elements seen so far and insert the number, then get factorial. Also, do you always get a runtime error (and which one) or just on particular inputs?

Comment: Have a look at my answer @Arnav Luhadiya.

Answer (score 0):

The prime reason you got the runtime error was due to the recursion. Have a look at the constraints on the number of elements `n` as provided in the question: `1 <= n <= 10^5`.

Therefore, for relatively larger values of `x`, the `power(x)` function consumed more than allowed memory and caused the system stack to overflow.

**Remember, always avoid recursion if you can solve the problems using loops.**

I replaced the recursive call with a loop in the function and I got `Time Limit Exceeded`.

**Time Limit Exceeded** means, we have successfully avoided the **runtime error**, but now, we need to work on optimising the algorithm further.

Have a look at the following code with correct implementation of **modulo arithmatic** for large values of `x`:

```
def power(x, mod):
    if x<=1:
        return 1
    else:
        ans = 1
        for i in range(1, x+1):
            ans = (ans * i)%mod
            
        return ans
        
for _ in range(int(input())):
    mod = 10**9 + 7
    number = int(input())
    trees = list(map(int,input().split()))
    stack = []
    list1 = []
    for i in range(number):
        if len(stack)==0:
            list1.append(-1)
        elif stack[-1]>trees[i]:
            list1.append(trees.index(stack[-1]))
        elif stack[-1]<=trees[i]:
            while len(stack)>0 and stack[-1]<=trees[i]:
                stack.pop()
            if len(stack)==0:
                list1.append(-1)
            else:
                list1.append(trees.index(stack[-1]))
        stack.append(trees[i])
    list2 = [0]*number
    for i in range(number):
        list2[i]= i- list1[i]
    x = max(list2)
    print(power(x, mod)%mod)
```

**PS:** As the runtime error is avoided, I suggest you to optimise your code further.